# syntax error specific range WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so the code works without WHERE but i need to add WHERE cause i want to display only the records where price is >400. When I execute this code

```
$results=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT aktfil.id, filmat.titulli, filmat.cmimi, 
 GROUP_CONCAT( Concat( aktoret.emri,' ',aktoret.mbiemri ) SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Aktori 
 FROM aktfil JOIN filmat ON aktfil.id=filmat.id LEFT JOIN aktoret ON aktfil.idakt=aktoret.idakt
 GROUP BY filmat.id ORDER BY aktoret.emri WHERE filmat.cmimi>'400'") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

It says

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE filmat.cmimi>'400'' at line 4

Comment: The WHERE clause needs to go ___before___ the GROUP BY clause [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: Please do *not* abuse the snippet tools. That is for HTML/CSS/Javascript *only*.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT aktfil.id, filmat.titulli, filmat.cmimi, 
 GROUP_CONCAT( Concat( aktoret.emri,' ',aktoret.mbiemri ) SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Aktori 
 FROM aktfil JOIN filmat ON aktfil.id=filmat.id LEFT JOIN aktoret ON aktfil.idakt=aktoret.idakt
 WHERE filmat.cmimi>'400' GROUP BY filmat.id ORDER BY aktoret.emri") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

The syntax of your query was not correct, `WHERE` clause should be placed before `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clause should be at the end. Also please use quotation `''` only if the data type of the column `filmat.cmimi` is some sort of text, otherwise use it like `WHERE filmat.cmimi > 400`

Comment: I think that the problem may be in trying to use numeric operator on string (number in quotas).